# Subtracting NSCountedSets filled with Swift structs

Tags: swift, nscountedset

I have two `NSCountedSets` and need to subtract them. For the sake of clarity, I am using a simple struct with one property as the objects:

```
struct MyStruct {
    let name: String
    
    init(_ name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

func subtract(_ set1: NSCountedSet, _ set2: NSCountedSet) -> NSCountedSet {
    var result = NSCountedSet()

    for e in set1 {
        let count1 = set1.count(for: e)
        let count2 = set2.count(for: e)
        let newCount = count1 - count2

        if newCount > 0 {
            for _ in 1 ... newCount {
                result.add(e)
            }
        }
    }

    return result
}

let set1 = NSCountedSet(array: [MyStruct("A"), MyStruct("A"), MyStruct("A"), MyStruct("B"), MyStruct("C"), MyStruct("C")])
let set2 = NSCountedSet(array: [MyStruct("A"), MyStruct("B"), MyStruct("C")])

let set3 = subtract(set1, set2) // expected result: ["A", "A", "C"]`

print(set3.count(for: MyStruct("A"))) // observed result: 0 (expected 2)
print(set3.count(for: MyStruct("B"))) // observed result: 0 (expected 0)
print(set3.count(for: MyStruct("C"))) // observed result: 0 (expected 1)
```

But if I for instance use:

```
let set1 = NSCountedSet(array: ["A", "A", "A", "B", "C", "C"])
let set2 = NSCountedSet(array: ["A", "B", "C"])
```

I get the expected result.

I suspect that each `MyStruct("A")` etc is actually not equal to the other ones since they are recreated. Which is what I see when I add a `print` statement, `count1` is always 1 and `count2` is always 0

So maybe there is a way that I can count the number of `MyStruct` by checking the `name` property, is that possible?

If not, is there maybe any other solution?

Comment: Problem must be in `MyStruct` [object wrapper equality check](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1393823-isequal). Or in hash function. Try to add `Hashable` or just `Equatable` to your struct declaration. Or just use `[T: UInt]` or something instead of `NSCountedSet`.

Comment: `struct MyStruct: Hashable` will work

Comment: Also, there's no need to write own substruction function, `NSCountedSet` already has it, inherits from `NSMutableSet`: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsmutableset/1416710-minus

Comment: Oh my, `minus`, I would have never thought of that one.

Comment: If I use `minus`, I get `'NSCountedSet' is not convertible to 'Set<AnyHashable>'`

Comment: Yeah, working with Objective C code can be quirky, probably `minus` won't work here

Comment: David's answer below has the correct syntax: `set1.minus(Set(_immutableCocoaSet: set2))`

Comment: @koen ah yeah, that's because of the Swift overlays for `NSMutableSet` APIs that tries to let you use native `Set`s where possible. That's convenient most of the time, but as you see, doesn't work with `NSSet` subclasses. The `Set(_immutableCocoaSet:)` is the escape hatch to shoe-horn a subclass of `NSSet` into a `Swift.Set`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make your type conform to `Hashable` to make `NSCountedSet` compare its elements based on their properties.

```
struct MyStruct: Hashable {
  let name: String

  init(_ name: String) {
    self.name = name
  }
}
```

There's also no need to define a `subtract` method, `NSCountedSet` already inherits `minus` from its `NSMutableSet` superclass

```
set1.minus(Set(_immutableCocoaSet: set2))
```

Be aware that `minus` mutates the set it's called on in place, rather than returning a new instance.

If you want to declare a non-mutating variant of `minus` without having to reimplement its logic, you can simply do that by copying the set, the calling `minus` on the copy.

```
extension NSMutableSet {
  func subtracting(_ other: NSMutableSet) -> NSMutableSet {
    let copy = self.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableSet
    copy.minus(.init(_immutableCocoaSet: other))
    return copy
  }
}

let subtracted = set1.subtracting(set2)
```

Comment: I changed this to an extension for `NSCountedSet`, so I could use the `count(for:)` function.

Comment: And equally, using `union`, I can add two sets.

Comment: @koen `union` would be great to wrap into a `+` or `+=` operator

Answer (score 3):

Arg, this is a frustrating feature of Swift I've been wishing gone for years now. It was occasionally handy in the early days of the ObjC migration, but it's now far out-stayed its welcome.

To help with Objective-C interop (which to be clear, was outstandingly important, and responsible for much of Swift's success today), Swift lets you pass non-`@objc` values in some places. Because Objective C only deals with pointers-to-objects, to make that work, the Swift values need to be boxed. Internally, there's an `@objc class __SwiftValue` that's used.

Frustratingly, this boxing is implicit (so it's hard to detect, apart from the fallout it causes) and worse yet, *it's only enabled when you `import Foundation`.*

Here's a demo to explain what's going on:

```swift
import Foundation

struct MyValue {
    let i: Int
}

struct MyValue: Equatable {}
// struct MyValue: Hashable {} // Un-commenting this will fix everything

@objc class Demo: NSObject {
    @objc func compare(_ a: Any, _ b: Any) -> Bool {
        // Do the comparison using `isEqual:`, which is what ObjC uses:
        return (a as AnyObject).isEqual(b)
    }
    
    @objc func inpsectClass(_ a: Any) {
        // `type(of:)` is cleverly implemented to hide the fact that it's happening.
        // it knows how to unwrap the `__SwiftValue` box
        print(type(of: a)) // => MyValue
    
        // `object_getClass` gives the honest answer:
        print(object_getClass(a as AnyObject)!) // => `__SwiftValue`
    }
}

let demo = Demo()

let a = MyValue(i: 123)
let b = MyValue(i: 123)

print("Does Swift think they're equal? \(a == b)" ) // => true
print("Does Obj-C think they're equal? \(demo.compare(a, b))") // => false

demo.inpsectClass(a)
```

Interestingly, this completely changes if you also conform `MyValue` to `Hashable` (instead of just `Equatable`). This triggers the `__SwiftValue` box to have `+isEqual:` and `+hash` methods which delegate to `==` and `hashValue` in Swift, which will make things work correctly.

Most frustratingly of all, Swift usually protects you from using `==` or `hashValues` on values that don't support them. This'll prompt you to implement the missing protocols. With the implicit boxing here, Objective C is allowed to call `+isEqual:` and `+hash` on these boxes, which give the wrong answers, without any indication that you're missing the `Hashable` conformance.

Answer (score 1):

I already made an answer that explains what's going on, but I'd like to chime in with some improvements to this code you might like:

1. listen to the warnings, `var result` doesn't need to be mutable (you modify the the pointed-to `NSCountedSet` object, but not the `result` pointer itself), you can just make it `let result`
2. `NSCountedSet` conforms to [`ExpressibleByArrayLiteral`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/expressiblebyarrayliteral), so you can initialize it with

   ```swift
   let set1: NSCountedSet = [MyStruct("A"), ...]
   ```
3. Your `subtract(_:_:)` free function is better expressed as an `-` operator on `NSCountedSet`:

   ```swift
   extension NSCountedSet {
       static func - (lhs: NSCountedSet, rhs: NSCountedSet) -> NSCountedSet {
           let copy = lhs.mutableCopy() as! NSCountedSet
           copy -= rhs
           return copy
       }

       static func -= (lhs: NSCountedSet, rhs: NSCountedSet) {
           lhs.minus(.init(_immutableCocoaSet: rhs))
       }
   }

   let set1: NSCountedSet = [MyStruct("A"), MyStruct("A"), MyStruct("A"), MyStruct("B"), MyStruct("C"), MyStruct("C")]
   let set2: NSCountedSet = [MyStruct("A"), MyStruct("B"), MyStruct("C")]

   let set3 = set1 - set2 // expected result: ["A", "A", "C"]`
   print(set3)
   ```

   4. When working with `NSCountedSet`, it's nice to have a convenient way inspect its contents. One easy way is to make a helper function that converts it into an array of tuples:

   ```swift
   extension NSCountedSet {
       func asTuples() -> [(Any, count: Int)] {
           map { ($0, self.count(for: $0)) }
       }
   }
   print(set2.asTuples()) // => [(main.MyStruct(name: "B"), count: 1), (main.MyStruct(name: "C"), count: 1), (main.MyStruct(name: "A"), count: 1)]
   ```

   You could convert it to a dictionary instead, but the result is much nosier:

   ```swift
   extension NSCountedSet {
       func asDictionary() -> [AnyHashable: Int] {
           Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: self.lazy.map { (key: $0 as! AnyHashable, value: self.count(for: $0)) })
       }
   }
   print(set2.asDictionary()) // [AnyHashable(main.MyStruct(name: "C")): 1, AnyHashable(main.MyStruct(name: "A")): 1, AnyHashable(main.MyStruct(name: "B")): 1]
   ```